# How to encode low bitrate / low quality MPEG2 video?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, encode, mpeg-2

Got some YUV420 1920x1080 60FPS videos i want to encode with MPEG2 with different quality levels. According to [stackoverflow: ffmpeg conversion to mpeg2video](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20078604/ffmpeg-conversion-to-mpeg2video) I could do it with

```
ffmpeg -i input -codec:v mpeg2video -qscale:v 10 output.mpg
```

The qscale parameter has a linear scale 2-31 and 31 is the lowest quality but it's not as bad as I would expect the lowest quality MPEG2 video to look like.

Also tried these:

```
-vcodec mpeg2video -maxrate 4000k
-vcodec mpeg2video -qmin 69 -qmax 69
```

maxrate gets ignored and i get the message that it is too low 
and qmin 69 quality is still higher than i want it to be.

Does anyone know how to achieve a really low quality MPEG2 video with ffmpeg or any other MPEG2 codec i could use to do this? Thanks

Comment: Providing samples might be useful for receiving help on this kind of question. Also you might ask this question on ffmpeg's irc channel (They're very helpful).